# Number of parameters in mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, aic, lme4-nlme

How can I tell how many parameters will be estimated for random effects in mixed models? Here is the example from the lme function in nlme:

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- lme(fixed = distance ~ age, random = ~ 1 | Subject, data = Orthodont, method = "ML", control=lmeControl(opt = "optim")) 
fm2 <- lme(fixed = distance ~ age + Sex, random = ~ 1 | Subject, data = Orthodont, method = "ML", control=lmeControl(opt = "optim")) 
fm3 <- lme(fixed = distance ~ age, random = ~ age | Subject, data = Orthodont, method = "ML", control=lmeControl(opt = "optim")) 
fm4 <- lme(fixed = distance ~ age + Sex, random = ~ age | Subject, data = Orthodont, method = "ML", control=lmeControl(opt = "optim")) 
fm5 <- lme(fixed = distance ~ age + Sex, random = ~ age + Sex | Subject, data = Orthodont, method = "ML", control=lmeControl(opt = "optim"))

library(AICcmodavg)
aictab(list(fm1,fm2,fm3,fm4,fm5), c("fm1","fm2","fm3","fm4","fm5"))
```

Can someone help me understand why K is what it is for fm1-fm5?

```
     K   AICc Delta_AICc AICcWt Cum.Wt      LL
fm2  5 445.44       0.00   0.72   0.72 -217.43
fm4  7 447.96       2.51   0.21   0.93 -216.42
fm1  4 451.78       6.33   0.03   0.96 -221.69
fm3  6 452.04       6.60   0.03   0.99 -219.61
fm5 10 453.44       7.99   0.01   1.00 -215.58
```

In particular, why does fm5 have 3 more parameters than fm4?

Answer (score 8):

- fm1

`fixed = distance ~ age, random = ~ 1 | Subject`

K = 4: the coefficients for intercept, and `age`; variances for random intercept, and error term.

- fm2

`fixed = distance ~ age + Sex, random = ~ 1 | Subject`

K = 5: the coefficients for intercept, `age`, and `Sex`; variances for random intercept, and error term.

- fm3

`fixed = distance ~ age, random = ~ age | Subject`

K = 6: the coefficients for intercept, and `age`; variances for random intercept, `age`, and error term; covariance between random effects of intercept and `age`.

- fm4

`fixed = distance ~ age + Sex, random = ~ age | Subject`

K = 7: the coefficients for intercept, `age`, and `Sex`; variances for random intercept, `age`, and error term; covariance between random effects of intercept and `age`.

- fm5

`fixed = distance ~ age + Sex, random = ~ age + Sex | Subject`

K = 10: the coefficients for intercept, `age`, and `Sex`; variances for random intercept, `age`, `Sex`, and error term; covariances between random effects of intercept and `age`, intercept and `Sex`, and `age` and `Sex`.

Comment: but then, is K the number of variables? All these covariances are parameters, right? so does the number of parameters depend on the number of groups?

Comment: @chuse yes, K the number of variables. It does not depend on the number of groups. We estimate the variance/covariance across groups. The covariances are parameters.